# Some conjectures based on surprising observations on magic squares

Tags: factoring, gcd-and-lcm, magic-square

Let us restrict ourselves to odd magic squares constructed using the Uniform Step Method of Lehmer (See [Apostol51] for the construction technique).

> A magic square constructed using Lehmer’s Uniform Step Method as follows:
>
> The $n^2$ cells of the square are denoted by the coordinates $(A,B)$ with  $A$ being the number of the column counting from the left and $B$ the number of the row counting from the bottom.
>
> The cell $(A_x,B_x)$ into which the number $x$ is entered is given by
> $$\begin{align}
> A_x≡p+α(x-1)+a\left[\frac{x-1}{n}\right]  \pmod{n}\\
> B_x≡q+β(x-1)+b\left[\frac{x-1}{n}\right]  \pmod{n}
> \end{align} \tag{1}$$
> where $(p,q)$ is the cell into which the number $1$ is entered, $(α,β)$ is the step used in proceeding from one cell to another and $(a,b)$ is the break-step that must be used when an occupied cell is arrived at and $[k]$ denotes the greatest integer contained in $k$.

**Definition.** Consider the $\Delta_{\delta}(x)$ the $\delta \times \delta$ submatrix of the magic square with $\delta$ odd and the element $x$ in its center. i.e.,

$$
\Delta_{\delta}(x) = \begin{matrix}
a_{i-[\delta/2],j-[\delta/2]} & \cdots & a_{i-[\delta/2],j} & \cdots & a_{i-[\delta/2],j+[\delta/2]} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{i,j-[\delta/2]} & \cdots & a_{i,j}=x & \cdots & a_{i,j+[\delta/2]} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{i+[\delta/2],j-[\delta/2]} & \cdots & a_{i+[\delta/2],j} & \cdots & a_{i+[\delta/2],j+[\delta/2]} 
\end{matrix}
$$

The arithmetic over the indices is taken modulo $n$ so that the submatrix $\Delta_{\delta}(x)$ is defined for all entries of the magic square, including the entries on the edges.

Define $G_{\delta}(x)$, the $\delta \times \delta$ GCD matrix of $x$ having $(i,j)$-th entry $g_{i,j} = \gcd(a_{i,j}, x)$ where $a_{i,j}$ is the $(i,j)$-th entry of $\Delta_{\delta}(x)$.

Consider the following $31 \times 31$ magic square.

$$
\begin{smallmatrix}
498 & 531 & 564 & 597 & 630 & 663 & 696 & 729 & 762 & 795 & 828 & 861 & 894 & 927 & 960 & 1 & 34 & 67 & 100 & 133 & 166 & 199 & 232 & 265 & 298 & 331 & 364 & 397 & 430 & 463 & 496 \newline
530 & 563 & 596 & 629 & 662 & 695 & 728 & 761 & 794 & 827 & 860 & 893 & 926 & \bf{959} & 31 & 33 & 66 & 99 & 132 & 165 & 198 & 231 & 264 & 297 & 330 & 363 & 396 & 429 & 462 & 495 & 497 \newline
562 & 595 & 628 & 661 & 694 & 727 & 760 & 793 & 826 & 859 & 892 & 925 & 958 & 30 & 32 & 65 & 98 & 131 & 164 & 197 & 230 & 263 & 296 & 329 & 362 & 395 & 428 & 461 & 494 & 527 & 529 \newline
594 & 627 & 660 & 693 & 726 & 759 & 792 & 825 & 858 & 891 & 924 & 957 & 29 & 62 & 64 & 97 & 130 & 163 & 196 & 229 & 262 & 295 & 328 & 361 & 394 & 427 & 460 & 493 & 526 & 528 & 561 \newline
626 & 659 & 692 & 725 & 758 & 791 & 824 & 857 & 890 & 923 & 956 & 28 & 61 & 63 & 96 & 129 & 162 & 195 & 228 & 261 & 294 & 327 & 360 & 393 & 426 & 459 & 492 & 525 & 558 & 560 & 593 \newline
658 & 691 & 724 & 757 & 790 & 823 & 856 & 889 & 922 & 955 & 27 & 60 & 93 & 95 & 128 & 161 & 194 & 227 & 260 & 293 & 326 & 359 & 392 & 425 & 458 & 491 & 524 & 557 & 559 & 592 & 625 \newline
690 & 723 & 756 & 789 & 822 & 855 & 888 & 921 & 954 & 26 & 59 & 92 & 94 & 127 & 160 & 193 & 226 & 259 & 292 & 325 & 358 & 391 & 424 & 457 & 490 & 523 & 556 & 589 & 591 & 624 & 657 \newline
722 & 755 & 788 & 821 & 854 & 887 & 920 & 953 & 25 & 58 & 91 & 124 & 126 & 159 & 192 & 225 & 258 & 291 & 324 & 357 & 390 & 423 & 456 & 489 & 522 & 555 & 588 & 590 & 623 & 656 & 689 \newline
754 & 787 & 820 & 853 & 886 & 919 & 952 & 24 & 57 & 90 & 123 & 125 & 158 & 191 & 224 & 257 & 290 & 323 & 356 & 389 & 422 & 455 & 488 & 521 & 554 & 587 & 620 & 622 & 655 & 688 & 721 \newline
786 & 819 & 852 & 885 & 918 & 951 & 23 & 56 & 89 & 122 & 155 & 157 & 190 & 223 & 256 & 289 & 322 & 355 & 388 & 421 & 454 & 487 & 520 & 553 & 586 & 619 & 621 & 654 & 687 & 720 & 753 \newline
818 & 851 & 884 & 917 & 950 & 22 & 55 & 88 & 121 & 154 & 156 & 189 & 222 & 255 & 288 & 321 & 354 & 387 & 420 & 453 & 486 & 519 & 552 & 585 & 618 & 651 & 653 & 686 & 719 & 752 & 785 \newline
850 & 883 & 916 & \mathbf{949} & 21 & 54 & 87 & 120 & 153 & 186 & 188 & 221 & 254 & 287 & 320 & 353 & 386 & 419 & 452 & 485 & 518 & 551 & 584 & 617 & 650 & 652 & 685 & 718 & 751 & 784 & 817 \newline
882 & 915 & 948 & 20 & 53 & 86 & 119 & 152 & 185 & 187 & 220 & 253 & 286 & 319 & 352 & 385 & 418 & 451 & 484 & 517 & 550 & 583 & 616 & 649 & 682 & 684 & 717 & 750 & 783 & 816 & 849 \newline
914 & 947 & 19 & 52 & 85 & 118 & 151 & 184 & 217 & 219 & 252 & 285 & 318 & 351 & 384 & 417 & 450 & 483 & 516 & 549 & 582 & 615 & 648 & 681 & 683 & 716 & 749 & 782 & 815 & 848 & 881 \newline
946 & 18 & 51 & 84 & 117 & 150 & 183 & 216 & 218 & 251 & 284 & 317 & 350 & 383 & 416 & 449 & 482 & 515 & 548 & 581 & 614 & 647 & 680 & 713 & 715 & 748 & 781 & 814 & 847 & 880 & 913 \newline
17 & 50 & 83 & 116 & 149 & 182 & 215 & 248 & 250 & 283 & 316 & 349 & 382 & 415 & 448 & 481 & 514 & 547 & 580 & 613 & 646 & 679 & 712 & 714 & 747 & 780 & 813 & 846 & 879 & 912 & 945 \newline
49 & 82 & 115 & 148 & 181 & 214 & 247 & 249 & 282 & 315 & 348 & 381 & 414 & 447 & 480 & 513 & 546 & 579 & 612 & 645 & 678 & 711 & 744 & 746 & 779 & 812 & 845 & 878 & 911 & 944 & 16 \newline
81 & 114 & 147 & 180 & 213 & 246 & 279 & 281 & 314 & 347 & 380 & 413 & 446 & 479 & 512 & 545 & 578 & 611 & 644 & 677 & 710 & 743 & 745 & 778 & 811 & 844 & 877 & 910 & 943 & 15 & 48 \newline
113 & 146 & 179 & 212 & 245 & 278 & 280 & 313 & 346 & 379 & 412 & 445 & 478 & 511 & 544 & 577 & 610 & 643 & 676 & 709 & 742 & 775 & 777 & 810 & 843 & 876 & 909 & 942 & 14 & 47 & 80 \newline
145 & 178 & 211 & 244 & 277 & 310 & 312 & 345 & 378 & 411 & 444 & 477 & 510 & 543 & 576 & 609 & 642 & 675 & 708 & 741 & 774 & 776 & 809 & 842 & 875 & 908 & 941 & 13 & 46 & 79 & 112 \newline
177 & 210 & 243 & 276 & 309 & 311 & 344 & 377 & 410 & 443 & 476 & 509 & 542 & 575 & 608 & 641 & 674 & 707 & 740 & 773 & 806 & 808 & 841 & 874 & 907 & 940 & 12 & 45 & 78 & 111 & 144 \newline
209 & 242 & 275 & 308 & 341 & 343 & 376 & 409 & 442 & 475 & 508 & 541 & 574 & 607 & 640 & 673 & 706 & 739 & 772 & 805 & 807 & 840 & 873 & 906 & 939 & 11 & 44 & 77 & 110 & 143 & 176 \newline
241 & 274 & 307 & 340 & 342 & 375 & 408 & 441 & 474 & 507 & 540 & 573 & 606 & 639 & 672 & 705 & 738 & 771 & 804 & 837 & 839 & 872 & 905 & 938 & 10 & 43 & 76 & 109 & 142 & 175 & 208 \newline
273 & 306 & 339 & 372 & 374 & 407 & 440 & 473 & 506 & 539 & 572 & 605 & 638 & 671 & 704 & 737 & 770 & 803 & 836 & 838 & 871 & 904 & 937 & 9 & 42 & 75 & 108 & 141 & 174 & 207 & 240 \newline
305 & 338 & 371 & 373 & 406 & 439 & 472 & 505 & 538 & 571 & 604 & 637 & 670 & 703 & 736 & 769 & 802 & 835 & 868 & 870 & 903 & 936 & 8 & 41 & 74 & 107 & 140 & 173 & 206 & 239 & 272 \newline
337 & 370 & 403 & 405 & 438 & 471 & 504 & 537 & 570 & 603 & 636 & 669 & 702 & 735 & 768 & 801 & 834 & 867 & 869 & 902 & 935 & 7 & 40 & 73 & 106 & 139 & 172 & 205 & 238 & 271 & 304 \newline
369 & 402 & 404 & 437 & 470 & 503 & 536 & 569 & 602 & 635 & 668 & 701 & 734 & 767 & 800 & 833 & 866 & 899 & 901 & 934 & 6 & 39 & 72 & 105 & 138 & 171 & 204 & 237 & 270 & 303 & 336 \newline
401 & 434 & 436 & 469 & 502 & 535 & 568 & 601 & 634 & 667 & 700 & 733 & 766 & 799 & 832 & 865 & 898 & 900 & 933 & 5 & 38 & 71 & 104 & 137 & 170 & 203 & 236 & 269 & 302 & 335 & 368 \newline
433 & 435 & 468 & 501 & 534 & 567 & 600 & 633 & 666 & 699 & 732 & 765 & 798 & 831 & 864 & 897 & 930 & 932 & 4 & 37 & 70 & 103 & 136 & 169 & 202 & 235 & 268 & 301 & 334 & 367 & 400 \newline
465 & 467 & 500 & 533 & 566 & 599 & 632 & 665 & 698 & 731 & 764 & 797 & 830 & 863 & 896 & 929 & 931 & 3 & 36 & 69 & 102 & 135 & 168 & 201 & 234 & 267 & 300 & 333 & 366 & 399 & 432 \newline
466 & 499 & 532 & 565 & 598 & 631 & 664 & 697 & 730 & 763 & 796 & 829 & 862 & 895 & 928 & 961 & 2 & \bf{35} & 68 & 101 & 134 & 167 & 200 & 233 & 266 & 299 & 332 & 365 & 398 & 431 & 464
\end{smallmatrix}
$$

For e.g., we can locate $949$ in the 12th row and 4th column in the above magic square.

If we consider the $3 \times 3$ square with $949$ in the center, we have

$$
\Delta_{3}(949) = \begin{matrix}
884 & 917 & 950 \newline
916 & 949 & 21 \newline
948 & 20 & 53
\end{matrix}
$$

We compute a GCD matrix by taking the GCD of the entry with the center element $949$ in this case i.e., $G_{3}(949)$. For e.g., $\gcd(884, 949) = 13, \gcd(917, 949) = 1, \cdots$.

The GCD matrix of the entries with the center term $949$ is:

$$
G_{3}(949) = \begin{matrix}
13 & 1 & 1 \newline
1 & 949 & 1 \newline
1 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}
$$

$13$ is a non-trivial divisor of $949$ the element in the center of the search grid, $G_{3}(949)$.

When we get to entries in the last row or first row of the magic square, we can wrap around and take the adjacent entries (by the modular arithmetic on the indices mod $n$).

For e.g., entries around $35$:

$$
\Delta_{3}(35) = \begin{matrix}
931 & 3 & 36 & \newline
2 & 35 & 68 & \text{from last row}\newline
34 & 67 & 100 & \text{from first row}
\end{matrix}
$$

GCD matrix for $35$:

$$
G_{3}(35) = \begin{matrix}
7 & 1 & 1 \newline
1 & 35 & 1 & \text{from last row}\newline
1   & 1   & 5 & \text{from first row}
\end{matrix}
$$

$7$ and $5$ are non-trivial divisors of $35$ in the search grid.

This led me to conjecture that we can find non-trivial GCDs in a $3 \times 3$ neighborhood of an entry in a larger $n\times n$ magic square. But that is not true.

**Counterexample.** Entries around $959$:

$$
\Delta_{3}(959) = \begin{matrix}
894 & 927 & 960 \newline
926 & 959 & 31 \newline
958 & 30 & 32
\end{matrix}
$$

GCD matrix for $959$:

$$
G_{3}(959) = \begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \newline
1 & 959 & 1 \newline
1 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}
$$

$959$ doesn't have any non-trivial GCDs in the $3 \times 3$ search grid.

For each of the primes the following table shows the multiples that are found in the $3 \times 3$ neighborhood:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{p} & \text{multiple in $3\times 3$ neighborhood} \newline
\hline
2 & 34 \newline
3 & 36, 930 \newline
5 & 70 \newline
7 & 903 \newline
11 & 44 \newline
13 & 78 \newline
17 & \text{exception} \newline
19 & \text{exception} \newline
23 & \text{exception} \newline
29 & 957 \newline
31 & \text{exception} \newline
\end{matrix}
$$

For the exception cases, if we expand the GCD matrix to $5 \times 5$ or $7 \times 7$ we find  non-trivial multiples in those expanded matrices.

When we expand to $5\times 5$ grid:

- for $17$, we find $51$;
- for $23$ we find $920$;

When we expand to $7 \times 7$ grid:

- for $19$, we find $817, 950$

This brings up some interesting conjectures.

**Conjecture 1.** For any composite $x$ there is a minimal odd square grid with dimensions $\delta \times \delta$ centered on $x$ that contains entry $y$ with non-trivial $\gcd(x,y)$. An obvious upper bound for $\delta$ is $n$, the dimension of the magic square itself. We conjecture that the minimal odd square grid dimensions $\delta \ll n$.

1. Can we say anything about the size of the minimal odd square grid for a given $x$?
2. Can we give a probability of finding an entry $y$ in the neighborhood with a non-trivial $\gcd(x,y)$ in an odd square grid centered on $x$ with dimensions $\delta \times \delta$?

**Conjecture 2.** For a given $x$ there exists an odd magic square of dimensions $n \times n$ containing $y$ such that a non-trivial $\gcd(x,y)$ lies in a neighborhood grid of dimensions $\delta \times \delta$

1. Can we prove or disprove this?
2. If true, can we derive sharp bounds for $n, \delta$ based on $x$.

**Conjecture 3.** The criteria for the magic square are given in [Apostol51]:

> The square is magic iff
>
> - $\alpha, \beta, a$ and $b$ are prime to $n$
> - $\begin{vmatrix}
>        \alpha & a\\ 
>        \beta & b
>   \end{vmatrix}$ is prime to $n$

So, we conjecture that $\exists \alpha, \beta, a, b$ prime to $n$ and $\begin{vmatrix}
     \alpha & a\\ 
     \beta & b
\end{vmatrix}$ prime to $n$ such that for composite $x = pq, p\ne 1, q\ne 1$, where $p,q$ not necessarily prime, $p$ lies in the $8$-neighborhood of $x$ (i.e., the $3\times 3$ GCD matrix centered on $x$).

1. Can we prove this?
2. If true, can we devise a method to select the parameters $\alpha, \beta, a, b$ based on $x, n$.

> *Update on Conjecture 3.* 50 primes greater than $10000$ were taken and semi-primes constructed by taking prime pairs from that set. For all those semi-primes $N=pq$, we constructed Uniform Step magic squares using Lehmer's construction with $n = \lceil \sqrt{N} \rceil$. If $n$ was even, we took the next odd number $n+1$. Then, [using brute-force](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4755222), we generated quadruples $(\alpha, \beta, a, b)$ satisfying the magic square conditions. We then solved for the $8$-neighbors of $N$ in the magic square using Eqn. $(1)$ and checked the GCD for non-triviality in the GCD matrix. In every one of those cases, a non-trivial GCD was found, strengthening the conjecture.
>
> A formal proof for all odd $n$, remains to be proven.
>
> *Related:* See separate [related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4755222) on improving the brute-force algorithm for generating the quadruples.

**References:**

[Apostol51]: Apostol, T. M., and Herbert S. Zuckerman. “On Magic Squares Constructed by the Uniform Step Method.” Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, vol. 2, no. 4, 1951, pp. 557–65. JSTOR, https://doi.org/10.2307/2032007. Accessed 17 Aug. 2023.

Comment: I don't get what are you doing in the first examples. "Coincidentally"? I don't see any coincidence. "Counterexample"? Counterexample to what?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I pick an entry $x$ in the $n\times n$ magic square and look at its $3 \times 3$ neighborhood. Then I take the GCD of the entries in the neighborhood with the center element. I am observing that in many cases, non-trivial GCDs are in the neighborhood. There are counterexamples for $3 \times 3$ where there is no non-trivial GCD in the neighborhood, but if we expand it to $5 \times 5$ or $7 \times 7$ we keep finding non-trivial GCDs. Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this has anything to do with the large square being a magic square? Does the same thing happen if you put $1$..$n^2$ in a random order in the square? Or is it due to the method that was used to create the magic square? The particularly high number of $3$'s in the GCD's is surely just due to the method.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: It is probably likely to occur if $1,2,\cdots,n^2$ are placed in a random order. But, I wanted to see if we could systematically move from one magic square to the next by modifying the parameters $(\alpha, \beta, a, b)$ for a given $n$ dependent on $N$ and then trying to force the integers that share a divisor with $N$ into its $\delta \times \delta$ neighborhood. The fact that it is a magic square gives it a highly regular structure and imposes congurence constraints on the neighbors.

Comment: ... In Eqn (1), if we put $x = km$ and $x = k$ we get a system of $4$ modular equations. If we then force $km$ and $k$ to be $8$-neighbors then, we further constrain that system. Perhaps, that gives us criteria for selecting the $(\alpha, \beta, a, b)$. That's the line I am exploring now. The $3\times 3$ grid is the simplest such modular system we could have and explore.