# On generating certain quadruples

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

As part of running simulations [related to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4754526), I had to write a program that generates quadruples $(\alpha, \beta, a, b)$ such that

1. $\alpha, \beta, a, b$ are all less than $n$ and
2. $\gcd(\alpha, n) = \gcd(\beta, n) = \gcd(a, n) = \gcd(b, n) = 1$ and
3. $\gcd(\alpha b - \beta a, n) = 1$

and $n$ is an odd integer.

The brute-force method I use is given in pseudocode below:

```
for alpha = 1 to n-1
   if(gcd(alpha, n) == 1)
     for beta = alpha+1 to n-1
       if(gcd(beta, n) == 1)
         for a = beta+1 to n-1
           if(gcd(a, n) == 1)
             for b = a+1 to n
               if(gcd(b, n) == 1)
                  if(gcd(alpha*b - beta*a, n) == 1)
                    yield (alpha, beta, a, b)
                  end if
               end if
             next
           end if
         next
       end if
     next
   end if
next
```

Is there a more efficient way to generate these quadruples?

Comment: For starters, you could first generate the list of coprimes to $n$ and then iterate over that four times. And check whether $\alpha b-\beta a$ is in that list. Not sure how fast your $\gcd$ function is, but checking comprehension in a sorted list is probably faster.

Comment: Your program appears to add the arbitrary restriction that $\alpha < \beta < a < b$, which is not in your list of constraints. The four variables do not appear to play a symmetric role in your constraints, and I see no reason to exclude solutions where $\alpha \leq a \leq \beta \leq b$, for instance.

Comment: @Stef you are right about that observation. For e.g., If I brute-force the range $1, 2, \cdots, n$ for $n = 39$, I would get $152064$ possible quadruples whereas with the inequality constraint added, I get $4836$ possible quadruples. Since the subset meets my simulation requirement, I went with it.

Comment: In fact, your problem is equivalent to the problem of enumerating those elements of the group $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_n)$ all entries of which are reversible in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$.